# How can I run a timer for 10 minutes and then disable the button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, timer

I took help from :http://forum.codecall.net/topic/65434-c-working-with-timers/ (in it a decremented counter is used, but it's not working in my app)

I have some text field and two buttons: submit and update.
I have implemented a timer from toolbar to update button.

I wanted this timer to run for 10 minutes and then disable the update button. But presently it's running for just 2 minutes.

Buttons Code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Btnsave" runat="server" CssClass="bt3dbuttons" 
    onclick="Btnsave_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Data Submitted')" 
    Text="Submit" Width="77px" />

<asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" ontick="Timer2_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:Button ID="Butnupdate" runat="server" CssClass="btupbuttons" 
    onclick="Btnupdate_Click" Text="Update" visible="false" Width="85px" />
```

Here is the code for timer:

```
private System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(600000)
                                                { AutoReset = false };
protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(600000);
   aTimer.Interval = 600000;
   double counter = aTimer.Interval;

   counter++;
   if (counter >= 600000)
   {    
       Butnupdate.Enabled = false;
       MessageBox.Show("Time Up!");
   }
}
```

Code for Update Button:

```
protected void Btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    string id = Id.Text.Trim();
    string name = Name.Text;
    string project = Project.Text;
    string result = Total.Text;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CM_Connection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        try
        {
            //lets check that the user typed the first number
            if (Viva.Text.Length > 1)
            {
                VivaLabel.Text = "Please enter a valid number to add.";
                return;
            }

            //lets check that the user typed the second number
            else if (Presentation.Text.Length > 1)
            {
                PresentationLabel.Text = "Please enter a valid number to add.";
                return;
            }
            else if (Confidence.Text.Length > 1)
            {
                ConfidenceLabel.Text = "Please enter a valid number to add.";
                return;
            }

            else if (System.Text.Length > 1)
            {
                SystemLabel.Text = "Please enter a valid number to add.";
                return;
            }
            //Now we have valid inputs
            //Lets put them into integer values

            int number1 = int.Parse(Viva.Text);
            int number2 = int.Parse(Presentation.Text);
            int number3 = int.Parse(Confidence.Text);
            int number4 = int.Parse(System.Text);
            //Now lets add the numbers
            int total = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4;

            //lets place it into the TextBox3
            Total.Text = total.ToString();

            //  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Result SET Name = @name, Project = @project, Result = @result WHERE ID = @id";
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name ", Name.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project ", Project.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result ", Total.Text.ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            //Report error to user in the bottom Label
            MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you assign the event handler for your timer? What triggers `Timer2_Tick`? I think you need to show us a little bit more code.

Comment: This code doesn't make any logical sense to me

Comment: I'd have to agree with @Jonesy on this one. Can you back up a step and tell us what you're trying to do? It looks like you're trying to have a persistent `System.Timers.Timer` running on the Web server, but it's kind of hard to tell for sure.

Comment: @Jim Mischel its my first time to work with timer so I don't have any idea. I dont want a persistent timer but yeah it seems it gets persistent how to prevent it

Comment: MessageBox.Show on a web app? have I missed something, are you hosting  HTML page in a Windows App?

Comment: @Adrian its a web app. If its not the correct way then how to show the alert messages/notifications?

Comment: You could use a script to show an alert when the page postback, or show a previously hidden element....there's so many ways to show  a message on a web page, It's really another question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved by following code:

Create the timer ( default can be used from toolbox)
set the timer interval property

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" ontick="Timer2_Tick" 
            Interval="600000">
        </asp:Timer>
```

For reference see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.interval.aspx

Create the event handler for timer :

```
protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (timeLeft > 0)
            {
                // Display the new time left 
                // by updating the Time Left label.
                timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
                Label1.Text = timeLeft + " seconds";
            }
            else
            {
                // If the user ran out of time, stop the timer, show 
                // a MessageBox, and fill in the answers.
                Timer2.Enabled = false;
                Label1.Text = "Time's up!";
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't finish in time.", "Sorry");

                Butnupdate.Enabled = false;
            }
```

use the following in the button on which you want your timer to start:

```
timeLeft = 600;
                    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
                    Timer2.Enabled = true;
```

If you want to show the current system time or current time use

```
Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
```

I declared it into label and how to do it and above please have a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492144.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Here we go a timer to disable button after 10 minutes :)
Hopes it helps somebody as well :)

Answer (score 5):

Use this code as a guide

```
public class Timer1
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(600000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        // Set the Interval to 10 minutes 
        aTimer.Interval = 600000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use 
        // KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection from occurring 
        // before the method ends. 
        GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }

    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is  
    // raised. 
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Butnupdate.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Time Up!");
    }
}
```

Example taken from

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: I wanted the timer to execute when I first clicked submit button and run for 10 minutes . But one thing one every click on submit button the timer get restarted ? if not what happened then ?

Answer (score 3):

Set the Interval Property of the asp:Timer this will then postback the page and call the ontick handler

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" ontick="Timer2_Tick" Interval="60000">
        </asp:Timer>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.interval.aspx

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the `System.Timers.Timer` on the server code it wont get used unless you page processing takes an extraordinary long time.

Answer (score 1):

Your timer may be getting garbage collected if it is a long-running method instead of as part of the class, I cannot tell by the code posted.

Read the [Timer.Interval Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx) documentation, which also has a sample of how to implement a timer.

Comment: 600000 is quite a long timer interval, I think the above poster may very well be onto something.

Comment: Karl is right - if the main class is disposed, then the event may not fire up.

Comment: @Karl Anderson yes i am also thinking that its getting garbage collected. How to prevent it?

Comment: @user2366842 10 minutes = 600000  milliseconds

Comment: @OnoSendai in my answer i included how to avoid garbage collection

Comment: Ah, good hint, @MauricioGracia - but just out of curiosity, if the Timer is added to the GC KA reference list but the invoker class is not, won't the Elapsed callback lose its reference and not call the OnTimeEvent, since it only existed on the now non-existent invoker object?

Comment: @Mauricio Gracia Thanks I get it how to avoid garbage collection

Comment: @user2684131 can you give a try to my answer and let me know if what OneSendai mentions happens ?

Comment: You cant keep a Timer running like that on an asp.net page. Once the postback is done, the timer is gone, with the page. You could set it up in the Application level...but there's no normal way to post to your user...

Answer (score 1):

[According to the System.Timers.Timer class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), it fires up an event once the the defined time is elapsed, in an asynchronous way.

The setup code would look like this:

```
        var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10 * 60 * 1000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

And the event itself like this:

```
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do your event management here.
    }
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: why you set aTimer.Interval = 2000;

Comment: My mistake while copying and adapting the code for your specific need - since the value is informed at initialization time, there is no need to set it. I'll edit.

Comment: @#OnoSendai Thanks I am trying you given method let see