# ASP.net cooldown timer attached to a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, timer, webforms

I'm looking for a cooldown timer which is activated after a click of a button.
I tried something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282260/run-timer-for-10-minutes-and-then-disable-button-c-sharp), but it's still not doing the job I need.

Here's my button code

```
<asp:Button ID="schlbtn1" runat="server" Text="Go To Lectures" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" OnClick="schlbtn1_Click" Visible="true" ForeColor="Black" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

This button has it's own code for executing some other stuff but I'm not sure if the timer's code behind should be added to the button's method or make a separate one.

Edited: By cooldown timmer I mean that i need a pop out box which displays the remaining time and until the timer didn't hit 0, the client should not be able to use the page.

Comment: What exactly is a "cooldown timer"?  Are you trying to have a timer run client-side or server-side?  What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: By cooldown timer i mean that i need the page to "freeze" or not to be able to use till the timer hits 0 seconds.